# Is putObject in AmazonS3Client blocking?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Do you know if the method -

```
public PutObjectResult putObject(PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest)
```

in `AmazonS3Client` blocking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes it is blocking, it returns a result. If you want to do more sophisticated uploads, look at this:

```
DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain credentialProviderChain = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(
           credentialProviderChain.getCredentials());
Upload myUpload = tx.upload(myBucket, myFile.getName(), myFile);

// You can poll your transfer's status to check its progress
if (myUpload.isDone() == false) {
   System.out.println("Transfer: " + myUpload.getDescription());
   System.out.println("  - State: " + myUpload.getState());
   System.out.println("  - Progress: "
                   + myUpload.getProgress().getBytesTransferred());
}

// Transfers also allow you to set a <code>ProgressListener</code> to receive
// asynchronous notifications about your transfer's progress.
myUpload.addProgressListener(myProgressListener);

// Or you can block the current thread and wait for your transfer to
// to complete. If the transfer fails, this method will throw an
// AmazonClientException or AmazonServiceException detailing the reason.
myUpload.waitForCompletion();

// After the upload is complete, call shutdownNow to release the resources.
tx.shutdownNow();
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html

Comment: The fact that it returns a result doesn't make it non blocking. Any other indicator that it indeed returns a result after the data was actually written?

Comment: if it returns a result that indicates that it is done it must by definition wait until it knows when it's done... From the documentation of the putObject method "Amazon S3 never stores partial objects; if during this call an exception wasn't thrown, the entire object was stored." so this call blocks until the upload is finished or errored